# WiX Bootstrapper doesn't start/work

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

Ive a problemm with my wix bootstrapper to install .Net 4 and my application(.msi generated with wix 3.7). When i compile my solution everything is ok, and the generated exe has the right size(not sure if important, when i use winrar to open the exe there are just a few files in it, and not the files i want to install).
When i double click my exe nothing happens(with and without administrator).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="asdf"
          UpgradeCode="{D188D758-2913-4BA8-B9BA-FEC5B4BCCBD7}">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    <Chain>
      <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="Myapp" SourceFile="$(var.Myapp.TargetPath)"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
  <Fragment>
    <!-- Check for .NET 4.0 -->
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                         Value="Version"
                         Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                         Value="Version"
                         Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion"
                         Win64="yes" />
    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
      <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full"
                  DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0"
                  DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/2/562A10F9-C9F4-4313-A044-9C94E0A8FAC8/dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe"
                  Compressed="no"
                  Cache="yes"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Permanent="yes"
                  Protocol="netfx4"
                  Vital="yes"
                  SourceFile=".\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/passive /norestart"
                  DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)" />
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Myapp.msi is imported as reference in the bootstrapper projekt.

May someone can help me where ive to look(iam not sure if im able to create a logfile)
if theres any code i should post pls let me know

Thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried including the "Compressed" attribute for your MSIPackage entry?  For example:

```
<Chain>
      <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="Myapp" SourceFile="$(var.Myapp.TargetPath)" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" />
</Chain>
```

The "Compressed" attribute tells Burn to include your msi in the generated bootstrapper package.  The "Vital" attribute tells Burn that your msi is required.

Also, burn packages write logs to your temp. directory.  So look in there if it still fails.

Comment: fyi: I used a variable of wrong type - numeric instead of version - thus writing "1.0.0" failed